How to set a destination in NavBuilder.navigation as startDestination with Jetpack Compose type safe navigation?
Is it possible set start destination of a NavGraph to a destination in NavGraphBuilder.navigation(){}?
private fun NavGraphBuilder.addNavGraph(navController: NavController) {

    composable<RouteA> {
        RouteAScreen(navController)
    }

    navigation<HomeGraph>(
        startDestination = RouteB
    ) {
        composable<RouteB> {
            RouteBScreen(navController)
        }

        composable<RouteC>(
            deepLinks = listOf(
                navDeepLink<RouteC>(basePath = "$uri/routeC")
            )
        ) {
            RouteCScreen(navController)
        }

        composable<RouteD>(
            deepLinks = listOf(
                navDeepLink<RouteC>(basePath = "$uri/routeD")
            )
        ) {
            RouteDScreen(navController)
        }
    }
}

I tested with NavHost with builder and creating graph as
@Preview
@Composable
fun NavCreateTest() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    // This NavGraph will be used with NavHost this navHostController will be assigned
    val navGraph: NavGraph = remember {
        navController.createGraph(
            startDestination = RouteC
        ) {
            addNavGraph(navController)
        }
    }

    Column {
    /*
        NavHost(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            navController = navController,
            graph = navGraph,
        )
*/
        NavHost(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = RouteC
        ) {
            addNavGraph(navController)
        }
    }
}

If i set RouteC i get following exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find startDestination
com.packageName.RouteC from NavGraph. Ensure the starting
NavDestination was added with route from KClass.

Routes and deeplink
const val uri = "test://www.example.com"

@Serializable
object RouteA

@Serializable
object RouteB

@Serializable
object RouteC

@Serializable
object RouteD

I also tried changing destination conditionally if deeplink is not null as
val intent: Intent? = (LocalContext.current as? MainActivity)?.intent
val deeplink: Uri? = intent?.data
val isDeeplink = deeplink != null

NavHost(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = if (isDeeplink) RouteC else RouteA
) {
    addNavGraph(navController)
}

Also didn't work if i start app via deeplink from terminal.
